# Integer Division Algorithm Using Repeated Subtraction - Off by One Errors

Tags: algorithm, integer-division

The following algorithm for integer division works correctly when the divisor is a factor of the dividend. However, when there is a remainder, the quotient is too large by 1. E.g. it gives 10//3 = 4.

Is there a small adjustment I can make, for example in the `WHILE` condition to make it perform correctly for these values, or do I need to handle separate cases in the code?

```
DIVIDEND = 10
DIVISOR = 2
QUOTIENT = 0
WHILE DIVIDEND > 0:
    DIVIDEND = DIVIDEND - DIVISOR
    QUOTIENT = QUOTIENT + 1
ENDWHILE
PRINT QUOTIENT
```

Comment: (Check the spelling in the first line in the code block.) Try with dividend = 1 < divisor.

Comment: What would that look like in pseudocode please?

Comment: That was a suggestion for debugging, not for a code change. As an alternative to comparing `DIVIDEND` (`REST`?) to a constant, you could compare it to `DIVISOR`.

Comment: The `DIVIDEND` needs to be `>= DIVISOR`. Otherwise, the subtraction results in a negative number.

Comment: From where I'm sitting, that's a stroke of genius.